# Почему число конструкторов не равно числу деструкторов

Tags: c++, g++

Необходимо написать функцию Get() (Получить()). Количество конструкторов не равно количеству деструкторов.

```
#include <iostream>

class Coord
{
    private:
        double x, y;
    public:
        Coord(double _x = 0, double _y = 0) : x(_x), y(_y)
        {
            x = _x;
            y = _y;
            std::cout << "Constructor is run" << std::endl;
        }
        ~Coord()
        {
            std::cout << "Destructor is run" << std::endl;
        }
        void Show()
        {
            std::cout << "x = " << x << " y = " << y << std::endl;
        }
        Coord Get()
        {
            return *this;
        }
        Coord& operator = (Coord obj)
        {
            x = obj.x;
            y = obj.y;
            return *this;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Coord object1(10, 15);
    object1.Show();
    Coord object2;
    object2 = object1.Get();
    object2.Show();
    return 0;
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка и как её исправить?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что при вызове `Coord& operator = (Coord obj)` происходит копирование объекта, а Вы не переопределили коструктор копирования, следовательно компилятор сам его сгенерировал. Можно это исправить(не вызывать конструктор копирования) передавая `obj` по ссылке, либо же добавить конструктор копирования:

```
Coord(const Coord& rhs)
{
    std::cout << "Copy constructor is run" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Никакой ошибки нет, при вызове `Get` срабатывает неявно определенный конструктор копирования, для которого нет логирования.

Answer (score 1):

Как уже было сказано в других ответах: проблема кроется в отсутствии определения пользовательской реализации конструктора копирования.

На этот счет в C++ с незапамятных времен существует так называемое ["Правило трёх"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%82%D1%80%D1%91%D1%85_%28C%2B%2B_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%29), гласящее, что если класс или структура определяет один из следующих методов, то они должны явным образом определить все три метода:

- Деструктор
- Конструктор копирования
- Оператор присваивания копированием

---

Помимо этого несколько рекомендаций по коду:

- Повторная установка значений для `x`,`y` не требуется, т.к. уже выполняется в инициализаторе конструктора.
- Функции-члены, не изменяющие видимого состояние объекта (`Show`, `Get`), следует объявлять с ключевым словом `const`:

  ```
  Coord Get() const;
  ```
- Передачу аргумента в оператор копирующего присваивания в каноническом варианте следует осуществлять по константной ссылке `const Coord& obj`. В общем случае, возможен вариант и передачи по значению, например, при реализации идиомы "copy-and-swap".